# ClickHouse: как сделать LEFT OUTER JOIN по трем индексам?

Tags: sql, база-данных, clickhouse

Две таблицы, meta и event, имеют три одинаково названных столбца с id. При этом в первой таблице всегда записаны все три id, а во второй только один из трех.

- id1 может повторяться
- id2 может повторяться в рамках id2
- id3 может повторяться в рамках id2

*Пример дал такой, что эти три условия не соблюдаются. Кажется, проще не обращать внимания на эту иерархию id.*

Нужно эти две таблицы слить в одну, при этом:

- заголовок результирующей таблицы должен быть объединением заголовков исходных таблиц.
- каждая строка-событие дополняется всеми meta-полями.
- строки из meta-таблицы, не имеющие сопоставления в event-таблице, должны попасть в результирующую таблицу с пустыми event-полями.

Все что я описал выше очень похоже на `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Только вот у меня никак не получается добиться такого же результат в ClickHouse. Либо заголовок остается от одной из таблиц, либо записи не дополняются всеми полями.

#### Пример.

**Таблица с метой**

```
| id1   | id2   | id3   | meta |
|-------|-------|-------|------|
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_1 | m1   |
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_2 | m2   |
| id1_1 | id2_2 | id3_1 | m3   |
| id1_2 | id2_3 | id3_3 | m4   |
| id1_3 | id2_4 | id3_4 | m4   |
```

**Таблица с событиями**

```
| id1   | id2   | id3   | event |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| id1_1 |       |       | e1    |  
|       | id2_1 |       | e2    |  
|       |       | id3_1 | e3    |  
| id1_2 |       |       | e4    |
```

**Ожидаемый результат JOIN'а**

```
| id1   | id2   | id3   | meta | event |
|-------|-------|-------|------|-------|
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_1 | m1   | e1    |
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_2 | m2   | e1    |
| id1_1 | id2_2 | id3_1 | m3   | e1    |
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_1 | m1   | e2    |
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_2 | m2   | e2    |
| id1_1 | id2_1 | id3_1 | m1   | e3    |
| id1_1 | id2_2 | id3_1 | m3   | e3    |
| id1_2 | id2_3 | id3_3 | m4   | e4    |
| id1_3 | id2_4 | id3_4 | m4   |       |
```

Comment: `FROM meta m INNER JOIN events e ON m.id1=e.id1 OR m.id2=e.id2 OR m.id3=e.id3` что ли?

Comment: В ClickHouse нету `ON`

Comment: Ну так переведите это в синтаксис ClickHouse. Главное - принцип соединения (истинность по хотя бы одному из трёх условий), и он не зависит от того, какие средства используются. Нет `ON` - поищите UNION, может, есть его у ClickHouse.

Comment: Вопрос именно по clickhouse. Я понимаю что основные принципы написания запросов +- одинаковые. Но ch имеет ряд особенностей, которые я по неопытности мог не заметить, и поэтому просто перевести запрос с sql не получилось (иначе зачем бы я задавал этот вопрос, в котором уже привел аналогичный работающий запрос на "чистом" sql?).

Спасибо за ответ. Попробую найти что-то по предикатам слияния в ch.

Comment: [offtop] *зачем бы я задавал этот вопрос, в котором уже привел аналогичный работающий запрос на "чистом" sql?* Я не вижу в Вашем вопросе SQL-кода, от слова "вообще". Но если Вы знаете текст работающего запроса - то зачем нужна вся шелуха с объяснением задачи, наполнением таблиц и прочими ненужными деталями? просто спросите, как именно в CH учинить именно такой тип связи... [/offtop]

Comment: [offtop]Чтобы не подталкивать к решению через простой перевод SQL-кода на диалект ClickHouse, в случае, если отвечающий знает другое решение. Скорее всего такое решение будет не самым оптимальным (если с нормализованными данными в olap вообще можно работать "оптимально").[/offtop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации, вашу задачу можно решить следующим образом:

1. Создать таблицу
2. Вставить в нее данные соединения по id1
3. Вставить в нее данные соединения по id2
4. Вставить в нее данные соединения по id3

В SQL это было бы эквивалентом

```
SELECT * FROM meta m INNER JOIN events e ON m.id1=e.id1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM meta m INNER JOIN events e ON m.id2=e.id2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM meta m INNER JOIN events e ON m.id3=e.id3
```

Answer (score 3):

В ClickHouse лучше так совсем не делать и денормализовать всё до одной таблицы events. Метаданные в зависимости от их природы либо добавлять в отдельные колонки при записи, либо доставать при чтении с помощью [механизма внешних словарей](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/query_language/dicts/external_dicts/).